# VBA: drag formula down to newest row

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a sheet in which I copy in plain data on a daily basis (while removing the old data). The copied-in data is located in column A:E while the formula is located in column F. Formula in column F is based on the data in column A.

Since the amount of data copied in varies from day to day, I'd need a VBA formula which automatically adjusts to the number of rows I paste in on a given day.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Viktor

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I've used on worksheets before. When you make a change to A1:E10 (or whatever range you set there), it'll pull down your formulas

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:E10")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("F2").AutoFill Destination:=Me.Range("TableName[columnName]")
    End If
End Sub
```

Formatting it as a table, then using the column name, is easier than trying to make sure you have the full range.Though you could also do something like this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set r = Range("F2:F" + CStr(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row()))

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:E10")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("F2").AutoFill Destination:=r
    End If
End Sub
```